# How would you handle pluralization of irregular nouns such as "person"?

Tags: api

If you were using an API where every resource was pluralized, and you came across a 'person' endpoint, would you prefer and/or expect `/persons` or `/people`?

I can see benefits to both and was wondering if there was consensus either way.

Comment: This is more of an English language readability question for developers... majority of us UXers aren't engineers who commonly use APIs. You may have more luck directly asking your API consumers.

Comment: @nightning I disagree. I think this is question isn't about readability. It's a valid question as it is about what *people* working with the API expect and how they interact with a system designed by another person. IMHO there's a lot of UX to be considered even if it's not the end user.

Comment: I agree with @msparer , developers are users of APIs and it is reasonable to consider this a UX consideration. Copy is often an important component of UX. I don't think I know enough about APIs and standard naming conventions for endpoints etc to answer effectively, especially as Jeremy wants to know if there is a consensus

Comment: If there are only a few cases, I'd implement both (using alias probably), so you don't need to explain. In general the answer by JohnGB is good, as it is a simple rule to understand.

Comment: "foot" and "feet"? The number of irregularities is not that huge, and a list can easily obtained in the 'net. I'd implement the "s" thing after having checked against the list. The list allows to say "foot/foots" or whatever if you ever wanted to do so.

Answer (score 6):

For clarity, what we have opted to do is **keep to the easiest to predict convention of using an "s" for plurals**, even if it's grammatically incorrect to do so.  Hence, we would use "person" for the singular and "persons" for the plural.

This has a few benefits that we have found:

1. It's clear to non-native English developers, and developers with poor language and grammar skills.
2. It's predictable in cases where there may be more than one option, or where someone may generally use the incorrect plural in daily lives.
3. If we sort fields alphabetically, the plural always comes directly after the singular.

Comment: Would it make sense to also support the correct version as an alias?

Comment: Programming isn't prose, so as long as you have a clear, consistent rule, I don't see a need for this.

Answer (score 3):

In the English language, “persons” is actually the correct plural of “person.”

The general rule is you use “people” when you are primarily referring to a *group* of persons whose exact number is not important, and you use “persons” when you are referring to *individuals* whose exact number is important. That is why you see “persons” used a lot in legal contexts — missing persons, persons of interest — where being precise in language and numbers is important.

In the case of an API, you also want to be precise in language. If you are counting individual persons rather than collecting people into an ambiguous group, you should probably use “persons.”